# How can I stack all faces of an object on top of each other in the UV Image Editor?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I've created a plane and subdivided it. Now in the UV image editor,  I want to unwrap and place all the rectangles on top of each other to share the same texture. Is it possible? If possible, please share your method.

Comment: In Edit mode with your subdevided plane selected open the **UV Mapping** menu and choose the **Reset** option. All the Quads will now be stacked one above the other and each completely fill the UV space. The result will be each quad will be mapped to your image but you may find that some of the images will appear rotated on your plane. These can be fixed by selecting the appropriate quad on the plane then going to the UV editor and rotate that particular island 90 or 180 degrees.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog can you write that as an answer so we can upvote it?

Answer (score 3):

1. In Edit mode select the subdivided plane:

[image]

2. Open the UV Mapping menu and choose the Reset option.
   Each quad of the subdivided plane will now be    unwrapped and mapped to the complete UV space. (Each quad will be stacked one above the other).

[image]

After resetting the Uv's sometime one ot more of the islands will be incorrectly orientated to fix these :

3. In the 3D editor, Face select mode, select a face that needs to be corrected. In the UV editor the appropriate island will be displayed, Select this face with the <kbd>A</kbd> key then rotate plus or minus 90 or 180°.

[image]

[image]